# Different result templates for indices instantsearch.js algolia

Tags: templates, algolia

I want to customize my algolia search results with two different item templates for two different indices, but I dont know how to do this. I also can't find a thing about that in the docu.

Here you can see how I have done it for now.

```
        <script type="text/html" id="hit-template">
          <div class="hit">
            <div class="head">
              <span class="title">@{{{_highlightResult.title.value}}}</span>
              <span class="tag">@{{{_highlightResult.category.value}}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
              <span>@{{{ article_votes }}} @{{{ comment_votes }}} Points</span> &middot;
              <span>@{{{ username }}}</span> &middot;
              <span>@{{{ created_at }}}</span>
              <span class="domain">@{{{_highlightResult.link.value}}}</span>
            </div>
            <p class="comment-text">@{{{_highlightResult.body.value}}} 
           @{{{_highlightResult.description.value}}}</p>
          </div>
        </script>

    search.addWidget(
      instantsearch.widgets.hits({
        container: '#hits-container',
        templates: {
          empty: 'Sorry, there are no results.',
          // Here I need two item templates one for comments and one for articles
          item: document.getElementById('hit-template').innerHTML 
        },
        escapeHits: true,
        transformItems: items => items.map(item => item),
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the recommended way to display hits from multiple indices using `InstantSearch` is to have one `instantsearch()` instance per index.

For example, in your use case, you would have one `articles` instantsearch and one `comments` instantsearch, responding to a single `searchBox` widget.  Each would also have its own `hits` widget.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hen395y0/) displaying hits from multiple indexes for inspiration.